# ADF Storage account trigger pipeline delete after use but data keeps coming

Tags: azure-data-factory

Azure Data factory pipeline gets triggered when files gets uploaded in Azure Blob Storage. Data factory waits 5 minutes and starts running. These are the tasks

1. Copies to SQL server
2. Deletes (soft delete enabled)

But between #1 and #2, more files where added to blob storage. How to prevent the second step from deleting these new data?

Comment: Are you deleting whole folder or particular triggered file after coping data to SQL server?

Comment: deleting all files

Comment: You are using delete activity to delete all files? Or can you share more information about how you deleting all files after copying data.

Comment: yes it can be file delete activity(with soft-delete enabled) or move the entire files to archive. Not sure how that is related.

Comment: you can use trigger parameters for file name and folder path to delete that particular file only from the source after copying.

Comment: so adjust the delete so as to only delete the files, processed, correct?

Comment: yes, So in between the process of copying data from one file to SQL database if you are added any file it will only delete the file which is being currently processed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252999/discussion-between-pratik-lad-and-blue-clouds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to prevent the second step (deleting all files) from deleting new data?

As we discussed in comment you can adjust your delete so that it only deletes the file, processed in particular pipeline not all files,

- Create file name and folder path parameter in pipeline as string
  [image]
- Then go to edit trigger and add details captured by trigger such as the folder path and file name of the blob into the properties `@triggerBody().folderPath` and `@triggerBody().fileName` to the respective pipeline parameters.
  [image]
- To delete the currently processed file you need to take delete activity and then create a dataset parameter to source.
  [image]
- Add this parameter in connection.
  [image]
- Add respective dynamic expression to each of the dataset parameter in a delete activity source respectively .
  **you can use the following dynamic expressions to fetch file path from trigger respectively:**

```json
To get Container name from folder path of trigger: @split(pipeline().parameters.folderpath,'/')[0]
To get folders details from folder path of trigger:@join(skip(split(pipeline().parameters.folderpath,'/'),1),'/')
To get file name from trigger : @pipeline().parameters.filename
```

[image]

> **It will delete the current file processed by pipeline trigger.**